# I am receiving an error when I start terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, macos-catalina

I am on a MacBook Pro, 13", Mid-2012. Currently running Catalina 10.15.1

Every time I start the Terminal, it pauses for about five seconds and spits out an error.

This is the order it happens:

*Open Terminal, this appears:*

`Last login: Sun Nov 10 20:21:54 on ttys000`

*Five second pause, this appears:*

`` (eval):1: parse error near `)' ``

`myname@Mynames-MacBook-Pro ~ %`

This has been happening since I updated to the Catalina beta back when it first released. Someone else said to check my zsh profile for junk. I believe I did what they said but I'm not even sure what the 'junk' could be.

Does anyone have any advice for me?

Screenshot of the terminal error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUjfD.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, this message seems generated from the profile or "start up script".
Then you can check them for any coding / grammar / format errors, including `/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc` or so on.

Comment: I went to the /etc/ folder and removed several files. I'm not sure which one did it, but the error no longer appears and terminal starts instantly. Thank you Geno.

Comment: @Dylan.Young What you should do is just comment out the target line not "removed several files"! You may unable to boot the OS completely if you accidently removed some core files of the OS! (Yes, this won't make any warning.) But... it maybe late...

Comment: No fear! Luckily I realized this was a poor move after my previous comment. Through trial and error I found the culprit file (zprofile in /etc/). I commented out those lines and moved the files back into their respective directories. Thank you for the warning, you helped me solve a problem that has been bugging me for months!

Comment: @Dylan.Young : If I were you, I would not simply comment things out, until the error goes away, but simply **fix** the error, because the author must have had some idea what he wanted to do there.